# Definition of temperature in Boltzmann transport theory

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, kinetic-theory, boltzmann-equation

In kinetic theory, the local temperature in a fluid is defined in terms of the average thermal energy of the particles, as
\begin{equation}
 \langle E_{th}\rangle= \int {d^3v}\frac{1}{2} m|\mathbf v-\mathbf u(\mathbf r)|^2 f(\mathbf v, \mathbf r)=\frac{3}{2}k_BT(\mathbf r)
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf u (\mathbf r)$ is the macroscopic flow velocity of a fluid element at $\mathbf r$.

I want to generalize this to condensed matter systems, like electron gas in a metal, for example. Does the above relation for temperature still hold, putting a relevant expression for thermal energy? i.e,
\begin{equation} 
 \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi\hbar)^3} (\epsilon_p-\mu)f(\mathbf p, \mathbf r) =\frac{3}{2}k_BT(\mathbf r) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

My thoughts were that temperature can defined more rigorously using thermodynamics. My attempt to solve the problem is as follows. From the first law,

\begin{equation}
 dU=TdS -pdV +\mu dN
\end{equation}

Because we usually deal with systems at a given chemical potential rather than the particle number, let us define the thermodynamic potential
\begin{equation}
 \Omega=U-\mu N=\int\frac{d^{3}p}{\left(2\pi\hbar\right)^{3}}\left(\epsilon_{p}-\mu\right)f\left(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{r}\right)
\end{equation}

The temperature should be given by
\begin{equation}
 T=\left(\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial S}\right)_{V,\mu}
\end{equation}

An expression for the entropy given the distribution function is the Boltzmann entropy:
\begin{equation}
 S = -k_B\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi\hbar)^3} f(\mathbf p)\ln f(\mathbf p)
\end{equation}

How do I calculate the derivative $\partial \Omega/\partial S$? Does the result reconcile with eq. (1)?

Comment: This seems like a question where the best answer is to read the first few chapters of a statistical mechanics textbook. The answer is a bit long to reproduce here, but it is very standard